# All files marked as new after cloning Mercurial repo

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I've just installed Mercurial and cloned repository from BitBucket. When I do `hg status` I see a log of files (looks like all of the files from repository) marked with `?`.

If I'm right it means that they are new. Why did it happen? I didn't change anything in repository since I cloned it.

When I do `hg diff` there's nothing in the output.

**UPDATE**:

Here are last three lines from `hg update` output:

```
running ssh -C hg@bitbucket.org 'hg -R original_repo/deploy serve --stdio'
remote: conq: repository access denied.
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

And here's `hg summary` output:

```
parent: -1:000000000000  (no revision checked out)
branch: default
commit: 51 unknown (interrupted update)
update: 544 new changesets (update)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're updated to the initial revision (numbered `-1`) which has no files, but you've still got the files locally, so they appear unknown (symbol: `?`).  It's not quite clear how you got there, but something's fishy.  You say the output for `hg update` include ssh stuff, but `hg update` is a 100% local commmand -- it doesn't attempt to access remote repositories at all, thus no ssh.  That might be something you'd see for `hg pull`, but we want to see `hg update`.

Can you please try `hg update` again and capture the full output.

In a pinch, just blow away your local-clone and re-clone from bitbucket.

Comment: Actually I get this error when mercurial tries to access original repository that I forked.

Comment: Why is it running this command for original repo that I forked?